# Crystal Reports Running total formula doesnt work

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

```
WhileReadingRecords;
numbervar Samples;
if {product.sku}="card-sample" then
    Samples = Samples + {@num_qty};

Samples;
```

Above formula always returns Zero, I know @num_qty has values in it and in some rows it has NULL, if I tried to evaluate NULLS using below code, it gives me an error too

```
if (not (isnull{@num_qty})) then
```

Any ideas ??? 
Note: I'm trying this because, for my situation I cannot use CR built in Running totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `Samples` variable assignment is wrong, and you need to use `:=` instead of `=`, like this:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
numbervar Samples;
if {product.sku}="card-sample" then
    Samples := Samples + {@num_qty};

Samples;
```